# Pandas grouping columns for writing to excel

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with columns like these

[image]

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([np.arange(6)], columns=['2019 col1', '2019 col2', '2019 col3',
                           '2020 col1', '2020 col2', '2020 col3'])
print (df)
   2019 col1  2019 col2  2019 col3  2020 col1  2020 col2  2020 col3
0          0          1          2          3          4          5
```

I want to save the dataframe to an excel sheet with the following columns-

[image]

Is there a way to do something like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create `MultiIndex` by [`str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html):

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.split(expand=True)
print (df)
  2019           2020          
  col1 col2 col3 col1 col2 col3
0    0    1    2    3    4    5
```